# Some doubtful implication for mathematical analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality, supremum-and-infimum, monotone-functions

Let, $f(x),g(x),f_1(x),g_1(x)$ are positive real valued bounded and continuous functions on domain of non-negative reals and also having range between $0$ and $1$. And, also,  $f_1(x),g_1(x)$ are decreasing function.

Now, if $\sup(f(x))\ge\sup(g(x))$ with $f_1(x)\ge g_1(x)$  then is it true that $\sup(f(x)f_1(x))\ge\sup(g(x)g_1(x))$?

If, $f_1(x),g_1(x)$ are constant functions, then above implication is true.

Is this true for non constant functions $f_1(x),g_1(x),f(x),g(x)$?

Comment: Even bounded functions may not have  a maximum. Do you want to change maximum to supremum?

Comment: @geetha290krm I have changed it, thank you for suggestion.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=0.5$, $g(x)=0.4$, $f_1(x)=e^{-x}$, $g_1(x)=2e^{-x}$.

Comment: @Peter thank you for the counter example, still is the implication false for non-constant $f(x),g(x)$?

Comment: Replace $f(x)=0.5e^{-x}$, etc.

Comment: In general, you can go about these constructions by assuming that $f$ and $g$ have their supremum as maximum at some $x_f$ and $x_g$ respectively, with $x_f>x_g$ and, hence, $f(x_f)>g(x_g)$. Then you multiply with some function $h$ which decreases sufficiently between $x_g$ and $x_f$ to scale down the maximum of $fh$ below the maximum of $gh$. This gives a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the following counterexample. For each $x\ge 0$ put
$f(x)=\frac{2-e^{-x}}{3}$, $g(x)=\frac 12$, and $f_1(x)=g_1(x)=\frac{1+e^{-x}}{3}$.
Then $$\sup f(x)=\frac 23>\frac 12=\sup g(x),$$ but
$$\sup f(x)f_1(x)=\frac 14<\frac 13=\sup g(x)g_1(x).$$

Comment: Thanks for the counter example, but what about the scinario when $f(x),g(x),f_1(x),g_1(x)$ are not constant, which is included in question...

Comment: @Alearner If you want to make the function $g(x)$ nonconstant, you can add to it $\varepsilon e^{-x}$ for any $0<\varepsilon<\frac 16$.

Comment: Can i have your mail?

Comment: @Alearner My last address can be found at [my papers](https://arxiv.org/find/grp_cs,grp_math/1/au:+Ravsky/0/1/0/all/0). My current address is alexander.ravsky@uni-wuerzburg.de